# How can I get name and other properties of transaction controller which consist of three requests?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

My script structure looks like that:

Transaction Controller SEARCHING OFFERS Transaction

- http request offers
- http request offers details

Beanshell PostProcessor

Which BeanShell command let me to get name, response code, response time, test result and test time for whole transaction?

Where I should attach BeanShell PostProcessor?
Which code I should use, but in my opinion

String name = sampler.getName();

doesn't work correctly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should be using **BeanShell Listener** instead of *Beanshell PostProcessor*. Listener can be at the same place where your current *Beanshell PostProcessor* is. That object has access to `sampleResult`, which would contain response code / response time / etc, for example:

```
sampleResult.getSampleLabel(); // the name, e.g. 'SEARCHING OFFERS Transaction'
```

Full list of SampleResult functions is [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
If you only want to process transactions in this listener, you could filter them (e.g. by name).

Comment: Kiril, thank You, I used code that You gave me and : String test = sampleResult.getSampleLabel();log.info(test); works fine for me, also String test2 = sampleResult.getResponseCode(); log.info(test2); works fine, generally all methods what are String type. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use method getTime() - it's long type, or getSampleCount() - int type. could you give me an few examples how to use methods, which are other type than String?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Do you mean something like `log.info("" + sampleResult.getTime());` or `long totalTime = sampleResult.getTime(); log.info("" + totalTime);` Or you could just append them all like this: `log.info(String.format("%s,%s,%d,%d", sampleResult.getSampleLabel(), sampleResult.getResponseCode(), sampleResult.getTime(), sampleResult.getSampleCount()));`

Comment: Yes, This is exactly I was looking for, but when I'm trying to start this code log.info(String.format("%s,%s,%d,%d", sampleResult.getSampleLabel(), sampleResult.getResponseCode(), sampleResult.getTime(), sampleResult.getSampleCount()));  following error appears

Comment: :2016/01/28 13:55:15 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``   log.info(String.format("%s,%s,%d,%d", sampleResult.getSampleLabel(), sampleRe . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Static method format( java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, int ) not found in class'java.lang.String'

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot that it uses an old style format: `log.info(String.format("%s,%s,%d,%d", new Object[] {sampleResult.getSampleLabel(), sampleResult.getResponseCode(), sampleResult.getTime(), sampleResult.getSampleCount()}));`